# Equivalent metrics to Euclidean meter

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I wanna show two following meterics on $\mathbb{R}$ are equivalent:

> $d_1(x,y) = | x - y |$
>   $d_2 (x,y) = | e^x - e^y| $

Could anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mainlines of the proof**

The map $f : x \mapsto e^x$ is continuously differentiable from $\mathbb R$ onto $(0,\infty)$. It is also strictly increasing. Therefore, it is a bijection.

Using the mean value theorem for $f$ and the inverse map (namely $\ln$), we get that for any finite interval $I \subseteq \mathbb R$, it exists $k,K >0$ such that

$$kd_2(x,y) \le d_1(x,y) \le K d_2(x,y)$$ for $x,y \in I$. This implies that the two metrics are equivalent.

Comment: I exactly have problem proving $kd_2(x,y) \leq d_1(x,y) \leq Kd_2(x,y)$

Comment: @Reza Take care that those inequalities are not true on whole $\mathbb R$, but only on **finite** intervals. Do you know the mean value theorem?

Comment: Yes I know the function has to be continous on an interval say $[a,b]$ and It also has to be diffentiable on $(a,b)$ then there exist an integer say $k$ between $a$ and $b$ such that $f(b)-f(a) = (b-a)f^{\prime}(k)$

Comment: But I can't exactly show the inequlities

Comment: Suppose that $x,y \in [-M, M]$ with $M>0$. By the MVT it exists $c \in (x,y)$ such that $\vert e^x -e^y \vert \le e^c \vert x-y \vert \le e^M \vert x-y\vert$. Which is $d_2(x,y) \le K d_1(x,y)$ with $K =e^M$. And so on...

Answer (score 1):

Well,  Let $B(a,r) = \{x\in \mathbb R| |x-a|< r\} = (a-r, a+r)$.

Let $E(a,s) = \{x\in \mathbb R| |e^x-e^a| < s\}=\{x| e^a-s < e^x<e^a+s\}=\{x|\log(e^a-s)< x < \log(e^a+s)\}=(\log(e^a-s), \log(e^a+s))$

.....

Fix $r$.

Let $t= e^a-e^{a-r}$ so $e^a-t=e^{a-r}$ and $\log(e^a-t)=a-r$.

Let $t' = e^{a+r} - e^a$ so $\log(e^a+t)=a+r$.

Let $s'=\min(t,t')$ so $E(a,s')=(\log(e^a-s), \log(e^a+s'))\subset (\log(e^a-t),\log(a^a + t') =(a-r,a+r) =B(a,r)$.

.......

Likewise fix $s$.

Let $r' = \min(a-\log(e^a-s), \log(e^a+s)-a)$.

So $B(a,r')=(a-r', a+r')\subset (\log(e^a-s),\log(e^a+s)) = E(a,s)$.

......

And that's the definition of equivalence.